# metasploit: how to use linux/http/webmin_backdoor

Tags: metasploit, backdoor

I am trying to gain access to a server using CVE-2019-15107 with help of metasploit. I tried to find examples of its usage, but I found none.

My machines ip is 192.168.109.133. I am connected to a vpn where I have access to the target at 192.168.208.32. At port 10000 Webmin is running with version 1.890, which is susceptible to this exploit.

I have set every required option, but it won't work, and I have no idea why.

[image]

This is the output after I exploit.

[image]

I have basically no idea what SRVHOST and SRVPORT is for. I don't know what TARGETURI is either. So if someone could explain that in more detail for me I would appreciate it.

Comment: You're using a VPN. How does the target route their traffic to your attacking machine? I'm thinking that this is not a security or a metasploit question but a basic networking question.

Comment: @schroeder maybe it is some sort of lab VPN where the routing works out.

Comment: @multithr3at3d sure, but that's why I asked the question

Comment: @schroeder Yes, I am connected to a lab enviorment via VPN. I was able to port scan the machine and find the service Webmin running on port 10000.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Does the target have a route to *you*? You can get to it, can it get to you?

Comment: Oh, yea. I can ping it. So I am pretty sure it should be able make a tcp connection back to me.

Comment: Uh, no. That's not how it works...

Comment: Oh, ok. How can I check if it works back and fourth?

Comment: So, my first comment applies. This is a networking question and not a security question. You need to know the network, VPN, and routing involved. You have chosen a payload that requires that it can connect back to you. But you are behind a VPN on another network. So, if you configure the payload to connect to your **machine's IP**, it must know how to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TARGETURI is explained in the description for that option; it is the URI path to the application. If you open a web browser to the application and the base of the path is e.g. /webmin, that's what you'd use here. Or, maybe there is no prefix and you can just leave it blank.

The presence of SRVHOST and SRVPORT indicates that the target will need to reach out to a server running on your end as part of the exploit. These just set where that listener will bind, so it can probably be left as default as well. If I remember correctly, Metasploit will use the LHOST value to populate the actual address when the target connects back to this server.