# What is the difference between SRVHOST and LHOST in metasploit?

Tags: metasploit, metasploitable

What is the difference between SRVHOST and LHOST in Metasploit.
I am testing an exploit in my virtual lab of which I had to set both options. LHOST was an option for the payload selected, while SRVHOST was included among the options to be set for the exploit. I believe SRVHOST and LHOST should be the address of my computer. I then tried giving SRVHOST a wrong IP-address and LHOST the right IP address, and the connection back to my computer was successful; but if I gave LHOST a wrong IP-address and SRVHOST the right IP-address, the reverse connection failed.

Why then do I need the option SRVHOST since LHOST performs the same function in my payload?    and
Practically, how can SRVHOST be used?

Comment: Relevant: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/238401/90657

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SRVHOST is generally the option that you set when you are serving a exploit on a web server and LHOST is the option you would set if you were using a exploit that is not going to be served on a web server.

Answer (score 0):

In case of ***staged*** payload, i.e. we actually send payload in 2 steps. At first the **stager** is sent to perform initial work (suppose, to disable AMSI, ETW, etc. for windows)/ download payload from attacker machine to perform in-memory execution in the victim machine, in order to bypass defenders, AMSI, ETW, etc. Then after performing the work, **stager** downloads the 2nd bulk payload (called **staged** payload) from host(attacker) from **srvhost**:**srvport** address (Webserver, where payload was hosted) and then passes execution to **staged** payload. Now after the execution of the downloaded **staged** payload, our listening **C2 Server** (**lhost** and **lport**) gets a connection back from the victim machine to build a reverse-shell connection (in most cases), offering us (attacker) a ***remote shell***.

Now, if you have noticed carefully, then you can see this thing,at the end:

```
[*] Server stopped.
```

This is the established connection which our **stager** created, but now we don't need this, as it's work is done. So it is stopped.

##### See this post in reddit: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/hacking/comments/e0w6rv/metasploit_srvhost_vs_lhost/)